# Using select instead of fork

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

After looking at Beej's guide to network programming, I am trying to redo my server.c using select instead of fork. I am not too sure what is going wrong; my program compiles, but doesn't accept connections. I know that my loop containing i<=fdmax isn't functioning properly, but I can't figure out why. It seems like the if statements are not working appropriately.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

#define Connections 5

void SignalCatcher(int signum)
{
   wait3(NULL,WNOHANG, NULL);
   //wait(-1);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int listenfd,connfd,n, i;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
   socklen_t clilen;
   pid_t     childpid;
   char mesg[1000];
   FILE *inputFile;
   inputFile = fopen("movie.txt", "r");
   char returnMsg[1000];
   int fdmax, newfd;
   fd_set readfd;
   fd_set mastersocket;
   FD_ZERO(&mastersocket);
   FD_ZERO(&readfd);


   //Creating socket number
   listenfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

   //Setting up the internet address
   bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);
   bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

   //Listening for clients
   listen(listenfd,1024);
   FD_SET(listenfd, &mastersocket);
   fdmax=listenfd;

   //signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
   signal(SIGCHLD, SignalCatcher);

   //Infinite loop that waits for/accepts connections.
   for(;;)
   {
      readfd = mastersocket;
      clilen=sizeof(cliaddr);
      if(select(fdmax+1, &readfd, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
       perror("select");
       exit(4);}
      //connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);


      for(i=0; i<=fdmax;i++)
      {
       if (FD_ISSET(i, &readfd)){
        if(i==listenfd){
            printf("-SUCCESS\n");
            clilen = sizeof cliaddr;
            connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen); }



      if (connfd!=-1)
      {


     // if ((childpid = fork()) == 0)
     // {
         close (listenfd);

         for(;;)
         {

            n = recvfrom(connfd,mesg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);

            if (n == -1 /*&& errno == EWOULDBLOCK*/) continue;
            else if(n==0) break;
            //sendto(connfd,mesg,n,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));
        //write(connfd , mesg , strlen(mesg)); //both work
            //write(connfd , "" , 1);
            printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("%d",listenfd);
            mesg[n] = 0;
            printf("Received the following:\n");
            printf("%s",mesg);
            printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");

         }

     // } 
      close(connfd);

      } //if connfd!=-1
     } 
    } //for i<=fdmax
   }
}
```

Comment: When you say your program doesn't accept connections, do you mean the accept call fails, or does your program just block and never reach the accept call?

Comment: Currently, the first client will connect and be able to send one message. After that, the server does not receive any more messages. If client is terminated, I get the error "select: bad file descriptor"

Comment: Well, presumably your server is going into the for(;;) loop, so the code to accept more clients doesn't execute. the for(;;) seems to defeat the purpose of using select().

Comment: I think your `for(i=0;i<=fdmax;i++)` loop is not needed because you need to check only the `fd` in your set of one entry.  But I think `fdmax` will be greater than 2, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html

Comment: @SteveValliere Having 2 fd_set variables is a normal way of using select(), so you can easily re-initialize the fd_set you pass to select(). if(FD_ISSET(0,&readfd) would be wrong, that does not mean the first fd in the fd_set, it means fd 0 (stdin). You do not want to check stdin.

Comment: I believe close (listenfd); should be commented or removed. you must not close the listenfd socket.

Comment: @nos Then the loop from 0 to fdmax *IS* checking stdin, stdout, and every other fd up to the one just created for his listener.  Perhaps that is a problem?

Comment: @nos Even with the for(;;) , I don't mind accepting a set amount of clients. The problem is that I can't even accept more than 1.

Comment: @SteveValliere It does check those, which is wrong. But since it never requested any events from those file descriptors, they will never be set, so there's no real harm in this case.

Comment: @krikara in that case listen to what user2181624 said, and do not close(listenfd);

Comment: Originally, I used the for(;;) when forking child processes. After looking at http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/selectserver.c, I thought it would be the same as to leave it in there.

Comment: Okay, after commenting out close(listenfd), multiple clients can now connect. However, the server is not functioning as intended. Normally the server terminal prints out every message it receives, but it is only printing out messages from the first client that connected.

Comment: Okay I know what the problem is now. Multiple clients are connecting, but the server only prints out the message of the first client that connected. After the first client disconnects, it will print out the messages that the second client sent. How do I change this so the server prints out a message once it receives it? Before it was forking, so for(;;) made sense for the message printing.

Answer (score 2):

You can answer this question yourself by examining the functions' return values. In network programming, the usual idiom is something along the lines of:

```
if (foo() < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "foo: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        /* recover from error or... */
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

...where `foo()` is one of `bind()`, `listen()`, `accept()`, `send*/recv*()` and so on.

Go ahead and try. `errno` will tell you what's wrong.

Besides, it's unclear why you are using `select()` at all. All you do is listen on a single socket, and you close it as soon as someone connects. Instead, you could just `accept(listenfd)`.

Comment: While good advice, it's not the main source of the confusion in this code. The code close the listenfd, so that will naturally refuse further clients, and the code also goes into a loop only processing one connection at a time.

Answer (score 1):

firstly you should not close the listening fd it should be close while exiting the program. secondly we need to accept all incoming connections that are queued up on the listening socket.then if listening socket is not readable then an existing connection must be readable, so read the data for that connection. I just read once but u can read in loop for that connection until recv fails.

following code change should work:

```
   //Infinite loop that waits for/accepts connections.
   for(;;)
   {
      readfd = mastersocket;
      clilen=sizeof(cliaddr);

      if(select(fdmax+1, &readfd, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
       perror("select");
       exit(4);}
      //connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);


     for(i=0; i<=fdmax;i++)
     {
       if (FD_ISSET(i, &readfd)){
         if(i==listenfd){
            printf("-SUCCESS\n");
            clilen = sizeof cliaddr;
            connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen); 
              if (connfd!=-1)
              {
                    FD_SET(connfd, &mastersocket);
                    if (connfd > fdmax) {
                        fdmax = connfd;
                    }
              }
         }
         else
         {
            n = recvfrom(i,mesg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);
            if ((n == -1 /*&& errno == EWOULDBLOCK*/)  || (n==0)) {
                 close (i);
                 FD_CLR (i, &mastersocket);
                  if (i == fdmax)
                  {
                     while (FD_ISSET(fdmax, &mastersocket) == 0)
                        fdmax -= 1;
                  }
            }
            //sendto(i,mesg,n,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));
            //write(i , mesg , strlen(mesg)); //both work
            //write(i , "" , 1);
            printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("%d",listenfd);
            mesg[n] = 0;
            printf("Received the following:\n");
            printf("%s",mesg);
            printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
         }
     } 
    } //for i<=fdmax
  }
```

Comment: The server only repeats the first message a client sends. Then the client stays connected, but the server doesn't keep repeating all the client messages like it is intended to. I don't understand why it doesnt do that since it keeps repeating the for(i=0; i<=fdmax;i++) loop

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with changes and its working fine to me.
Also if you want only one client communicate with server at a time then enable the while loop for reading client data.

server.c

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

#define Connections 5

void SignalCatcher(int signum)
{
   wait3(NULL,WNOHANG, NULL);
   //wait(-1);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int listenfd,connfd,n, i;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
   socklen_t clilen;
   pid_t     childpid;
   char mesg[1000];
   FILE *inputFile;
   inputFile = fopen("movie.txt", "r");
   char returnMsg[1000];
   int fdmax, newfd;
   fd_set readfd;
   fd_set mastersocket;
   FD_ZERO(&mastersocket);
   FD_ZERO(&readfd);

   //Creating socket number
   listenfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

   //Setting up the internet address
   bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);
   bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

   //Listening for clients
   listen(listenfd,1024);
   FD_SET(listenfd, &mastersocket);
   fdmax=listenfd;

   //signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
   signal(SIGCHLD, SignalCatcher);

   //Infinite loop that waits for accepts connections.
   for(;;)
   {
      readfd = mastersocket;
      clilen=sizeof(cliaddr);

      if(select(fdmax+1, &readfd, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
       perror("select");
       exit(4);}
      //connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);


     for(i=0; i<=fdmax;i++)
     {
       if (FD_ISSET(i, &readfd)){
         if(i==listenfd){
            printf("-SUCCESS\n");
            clilen = sizeof cliaddr;
            connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen); 
              if (connfd!=-1)
              {
                    FD_SET(connfd, &mastersocket);
                    if (connfd > fdmax) {
                        fdmax = connfd;
                    }
              }
         }
         else
         {
            //while(1) {
                n = recvfrom(i,mesg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);
                if ((n == -1 /*&& errno == EWOULDBLOCK*/)  || (n==0)) {
                     close (i);
                     FD_CLR (i, &mastersocket);
                      if (i == fdmax)
                      {
                         while (FD_ISSET(fdmax, &mastersocket) == 0)
                            fdmax -= 1;
                      }
                    // break;
                }
                //sendto(i,mesg,n,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));
                //write(i , mesg , strlen(mesg)); //both work
                //write(i , "" , 1);
                printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
                printf("%d",listenfd);
                mesg[n] = 0;
                printf("Received the following:\n");
                printf("%s",mesg);
                printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
             }
         //} /* end of while */
     } 
    } //for i<=fdmax
  }
}
```

client.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 32000

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int sd, rc, i;
  struct sockaddr_in localAddr, servAddr;
  struct hostent *h;
  char message[1000] ;

  servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servAddr.sin_port = htons( SERVER_PORT );

  /* create socket */
  sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if(sd<0) {
    perror("cannot open socket ");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* bind any port number */
  localAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  localAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  localAddr.sin_port = htons(0);

  rc = bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *) &localAddr, sizeof(localAddr));
  if(rc<0) {
    printf("%s: cannot bind port TCP %u\n",argv[0],SERVER_PORT);
    perror("error ");
    exit(1);
  }

    /* connect to server */
    rc = connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
    if(rc<0) {
        perror("cannot connect ");
        exit(1);
    }

   while(1)
   {
        printf("Enter message : ");
        scanf("%s" , message);
        rc = send(sd, message, strlen(message) + 1, 0);

        if(rc<0) {
          perror("cannot send data ");
          close(sd);
          exit(1);
        }
        printf("To_server: data%u sent (%s)\n",strlen(message),message);
  }
  return 0; 
}
```